# Hive crashing on where clause

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, emr

I am trying to get a hive-hadoop-mongo setup to work. I have imported the data into mongodb from a json file, then I created both internal and external tables in hive that connect to mongo:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE reviews(
    user_id STRING, 
    review_id STRING, 
    stars INT, 
    date1 STRING,
    text STRING,
    type STRING,
    business_id STRING
     )
    STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"date1":"date"}')
    TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://localhost:27017/test.reviews');
```

This part works fine because a select all query (`select * from reviews`) outputs everything like it should. But when I do one with a where clause (`select * from reviews where stars=4` for example) hive crashes.

I have the following jars being added when I start up hive:

```
add jar mongo-hadoop.jar;
add jar mongo-java-driver-3.3.0.jar;
add jar mongo-hadoop-hive-2.0.1.jar;
```

And if it is relevant in any sense, I am using Amazon's EMR cluster for this, and I'm connected through ssh.

Thanks for all the help

Here is the error hive throws out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.deserializeExpression(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/plan/ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc;
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat.getFilter(HiveMongoInputFormat.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveMongoInputFormat.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator$FetchInputFormatSplit.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0):

Crete table like below and check.

```
CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE <tablename>
(<schema>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.BSONSerDe'
[WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='<JSON mapping>')]
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.BSONFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.output.HiveBSONFileOutputFormat'
[LOCATION '<path to existing directory>'];
```

Instead of using a StorageHandler to read, serialize, deserialize, and output the data from Hive objects to BSON objects, the individual components are listed individually. This is because using a StorageHandler has too many negative effects when dealing with the native HDFS filesystem

Comment: I'm getting this error now: `FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException No FileSystem for scheme: mongodb)`

Comment: On a related note, would this mean that hive will read the mongodb dump files instead of querying mongo directly?

Answer (score 0):

I see

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"date1":"date"}')
```

and you are querying the column stars which is not mapped.

Comment: The documentation says that the mapping is optional but to be sure I mapped everything. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I met this probelem on our cluster.

The cluster hive version is higher than version in mongo-hive(which is 1.2.1)

The old class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.deserializeExpression has been renamed to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializeExpression

You need to rebuild the jar by yourself.